# What is the fastest/most efficient way of caching billions of responses from an API?

Tags: php, mysql, redis, storage, guzzle

The API I am querying will take 5 parameters, call them A, B, C, D, E, do some calculations using a data store and then return a response with roughly 8 fields, which will all be stored. Unfortunately, this calculation takes a little long and is causing the user experience to be slow at best. It is worth noting this response will be on screen using a javascript app, and the surrounding tech is currently PHP 7.1, using Laravel and MySQL

My plan is to save each response in a table (or similar depending on the response) and then use these as a direct lookup, so an end user can enter A, B, C, D, E and get an instant response.

So, this question is essentially 2 parts:

1: What is the best way to query a restful API a billion times (or more) in a day? Currently, for similar scenarios, I have been using Guzzle Promises to send 5 requests at a time

2: Which tech is recommended for storing this data? It only has to be a single row or entity with no relationships required. This data won't be used in a join or anything like that. Currently, the plan is to use sharded MySQL, or use Redis (but my worry is with Redis is that eventually it stops being scalable, say for instance my requirement for data massively increases).

Any insights to either of these issues would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You should take a look at [help/on-topic] and [ask].

Comment: You need to rethink your strategy.  You cannot possibly query a REST API 1 billion times per day -- that is 11,574 requests per second, every second, all day.  If each response is 1KiB, that is ~1 TiB of data transfer per day, costing the API provider hundreds or thousands of dollars per month, not to mention the dozens of servers they would need to handle your traffic.

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding cache storage**.

As your API operates via HTTP protocol, the best thing you can do is to follow [HTTP Caching](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html). Basically, it means that you need to send proper headers in response, in order to activate ***expiration*** and/or ***validation*** caching models.

Also it means that **you do not need to code a cache storage**. You can use existing solutions of reverse proxies. For example, in AWS you can use [CloudFront](https://atenea.marfeel.com/atn/marfeel-press/systems-requirements/set-up-a-reverse-proxy-configuration/create-a-reverse-proxy-and-cache-using-amazon-cloudfront). If you maintain servers yourself - you can use Varnish or Nginx as a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0):

In this case our guess as good as yours. This kind of data manipulations depends on:

- What exactly your end-user need? (Personalized data or account-independent)
- How often the data is changing? (once a hour, day, week...)
- What is the cache time for API response? (yes, API also caches its response)

Let's assume that data you are requesting, changes ~twice a day and the data is not personalized. In this case you can set some CRON jobs to fetch the data 2 times per day, transform the data (use only needed data, calculation, etc...) and store them in your DB (MySQL if the data not so big, otherwise use PostgreSQL) and show to end-users data from your DB (it's much faster). Also may be useful to clean-up old data (last weeks, months, years...)

Comment: The data will be refreshed on a daily basis, and is personalised (thanks for pointing that out, there will be a single column that should be linked to whitelisted domains). All data will have a lifetime of 30 days unless updated. So a CRON task will be run each morning. API responses will be cached using Varnish

Comment: Personalized, you mean - per domain?

Comment: If the whitelisted domain matches the domain the information is requested from then allow, otherwise do not

Comment: Ok, then create a table with the list of all the whitelisted domains, and fetch the data for them on daily basis (via CRON) and show the data for users when you want, but you will always have all the data on your end